# Pure JS: Listen for onchange event?

Tags: javascript

This is giving me "4: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL":

```
(function() {
    var select = document.getElementById('select-card');

    ​select.onchange = function() { };
})();
```

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: Maybe the select keyword is bugging. It's on the window object.

Comment: Actually that's not it, you have a non-printing character in front of `select`. See [a red dot at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tj018y97/).

Answer (score 6):

I expect that you have an element with id `select-card`. Your code is otherwise fine.

But you should be using.

```
select.addEventListener("change", function(){  } );
```

Comment: This should not make a difference. It's preferred, but both should work.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the code to this: `select.onchange = (function() { });`
Whenever you're doing a function expression and calling it immediately, you need those parens because there's a parsing ambiguity otherwise.

Comment: Not true. Setting the `onchange` property via JavaScript should work on elements that support it: http://jsfiddle.net/jdcvn1d8/

Comment: Just found the error and edited it @mcbrute .Thanks for telling me, maybe I was the one confused.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't wrap my head around this. The code is correct however is was bugging still. Found it, it appeared when I converted my test page from UTF8 to ANSI:

There is a incorrect return/character in your code. That is causing the bug.